# VIM as a full-featured extensible IDE for any language

Tags: perl, vim

Hello I would like to master VIM as my primary IDE. I know there are many plugins etc. but I have one question: Is possible for VIM to understand the particular language (in case I wont plugin for my language) in which code is written? I mean some rules that I can define and then use e.g. for auto-completion, refactoring, folding etc. For example consider following two perl codes in which I want refactor variables. In first example there are variables with same names but one is scalar and another are array and hash, in second example same name of variable as was defined before was used in another scope (loop etc.). Thus refactoring using simple text matching is not elegant way I thing:

**1st example:**

```
my @same_name;
my $same_name; # How to refactor this variable without affecting all other variables?
my %same_name;

$same_name[0]       = 5;
$same_name{"key"}   = 5;
$same_name          = 5;
```

**2nd example:**

```
my @array;
my $already_existing_variable; # How to refactor this variable

foreach my $already_existing_variable (@array){
    print $already_existing_variable; # Without affecting this variable
}



print $already_existing_variable; # Variable that should be also refactorized
```

Or how can I achieve that when I type `$arr` {and hit TAB here} it will automatically extend to `$array[` ? For this VIM must to know that when I prepend `$` before variable which was declared with `@` I want to access array elements.
Another example would be: how to fold code using e.g. `BEGIN` and `END` keywords? Those was jut trivial examples but I think you get the point. I think it is similar task to write own compiler or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using vim with my perl scripts almost all days:

## Rename variables

`App::EditorTools` gives you the function to rename variables like `Padre`.

1. install App::EditorTool `$ cpanm App::EditorTools`
2. install vim plugin `$ editortools install-vim`
3. move cursor on the variable name in vim.
4. type `\pL`

I'm not sure why it parses wrong scope in the 2nd example, but you can temporarily wrap the `foreach` brock with lambda and rename variables inside the code block first.

```
sub {
foreach my $already_existing_variable (@array){
    print $already_existing_variable; # Without affecting this variable
}
}->();
```

## Reformat script indent

`Perl::Tidy` has `perltidy` command line tool to format your script.

1. install Perl::Tidy `$ cpanm Perl::Tidy`
2. create `~/.perltidyrc` according to your taste. like folowing:

   -pbp
   -pt=2
   -sbt=2
   -bt=2
   -bbt=2
   -ce
   -nbbc
3. set `equalprg` to `perltidy` in your `~/.vimrc`

   au FileType perl setl ep=perltidy
4. type `gg=G` in your script.

## Syntax Check

vim's built-in compiler plugin for perl does very well.

1. set `:compiler`to `perl` in your `~/.vimrc`

   au FileType perl :compiler perl
2. type `:make` in normal mode
3. type `:copen` to open up quickfix window

if you don't want `warnings` in your quickfix list, you can unset the flag for it.

```
let g:perl_compiler_force_warnings = 0
```

`$PERL5LIB` is also important while invoking `:make`, you can give specific directories in it.

```
let &l:path = './lib,./blib/lib,./blib/arch,' . &l:path
let $PERL5LIB = substitute(&l:path, ',', ':', 'g')
```

## Completions

vim has nice completion tool out of the box. see `:help comple-generic`

1. type `$ar` in insert mode and press `CTRL-N`

You might be interested in `ctags` too.

Comment: Thank you for tips. You said "almost all days" so what other IDEs/editors are you using and why?

Comment: Sometimes I use Emacs and Padre, but few. Only perl can parse Perl. Treating them as plain text has much better prospects than IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I can already tell something is wrong when the first sentence is `"Hello I would like to master VIM as my primary IDE."`

Vim is not an IDE. Vim is a text editor. (You can use google to find out more)

If you feel that the features an IDE provides (refactoring, smarter auto-completion...) are more important than the features that vim provides (fast movement, never take your hands off the home row, programmable editor...) then you should use an IDE, or an IDE with a vim plugin. Usually, if you want to mix IDE features with vim features, you do it with a plugin to the IDE, not the other way around (there are some exceptions such as eclim).

Comment: I want master VIM as my primary editor not just for perl but for other programming languages and also for text editing. Basically I am searching for something, editor or IDE, call it as you wish, that is highly customizable and configurable and as far as I know VIM is highly configurable.

Comment: What I would like is to master just one IDE/editor and write code here, and if some language feature wont be supported or some functionality that I've mention will be missing I will 'script' it in the IDE/editor that I already know. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: There are some things that would just take too long to script in for the amount of time saved they give you. I suggest just writing your code in vim (because vim is one of the few editors where it is easy to script, and you have already started with vim) and just deal with the fact that certain features from IDEs won't be fully available. For refactoring, I suggest using the `gc` flag on substitution (`:%s/someName/otherName/gc`) This will prompt you before replacing. For auto completion just use the built-in autocompletion, I think it is good enough